# Why does the set of all automorphisms on the additive group of integers contain only 2 elements?

Tags: group-theory, automorphism-group

I believe that $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x$ are the only two automorphisms.

But the set of automorphisms on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is isomorphic to $U_n$.
So as $n$ increases, the number of automorphisms on $\mathbb{Z}_n$ increases.
However, for the entire set of integers, there are only two automorphisms.

I want to understand why this changes at infinity.
Why isn't there a limiting property?

Comment: Well, there are only two elements because any element other than $1, -1$ generates a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$. Regarding the "limiting property", I guess the thing is that the infinite cyclic group isn't the correct limit of what you're after, but instead you are after its profinite completion. Maybe.

Comment: If you really want to think of it as a “limiting property”, think of $\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}_0$ (since $a\equiv b \pmod{0}$ holds if and only if $a=b$).

Comment: Good question, good answers. For extra fun, everyone rethink question and answers in terms of: Why does $\mathbb Z/n$ have "many" ($\varphi(n) \stackrel{n \to \infty}\longrightarrow \infty$) units, but $\mathbb Z$ has only two?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jose Carlos Santos has explained why the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Z}$ is very constrained, while that of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is not as restricted, leading to more possibilities.

Paraphrasing US Supreme Court justices, I write separately to emphasize that I don’t think it is conceptually a good idea to think of $\mathbb{Z}$ as being a sort of “limit” of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $n$ gets larger. It just doesn’t.

First, if you think of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, then $\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/0\mathbb{Z}$, so in fact $\mathbb{Z}$ isn’t what happens when “$n$ gets larger”, it’s what happened when $n$ was a small as possible.

Second, you don’t have (nontrivial) maps from $\mathbb{Z}_n$ into $\mathbb{Z}$: you only have maps going the other way. If you think of group morphisms as going “left to right”, like most of our function arrows, the $\mathbb{Z}$ is the *leftmost* group among the cyclic groups, not the rightmost. So there is not good way to think of $\mathbb{Z}$ as the “limiting group” of the $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Thirdly, you want to be careful with how you think of the $\mathbb{Z}_n$ “fitting inside each other”. Note that $\mathbb{Z}_m$ has a (unique) subgroup isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_n$ if and only if $n|m$. So it’s not a nice straight progression, but rather a somewhat complicated arrangement of these groups as they fit inside each other; what you get is what is called a “directed partially ordered set”.

Now, there is a way to try to figure out what the “limiting group” of the $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is; it’s called a [direct limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit). If you do that to the finite cyclic groups, you don’t get $\mathbb{Z}$; instead, [you get $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016124/union-of-all-finite-cyclic-groups), a very different group. And this group *does* have *lots* of automorphisms! You can decompose it into a direct product of Prüfer $p$-groups, and each of those has at least one automorphism for each unit of the $p$-adic integers (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1048116/automorphisms-of-the-pr%c3%bcfer-group)).

Comment: This is an excellent answer. I'd upvote it twice (once for $\mathbb{Z}\cong\mathbb{Z}/0\mathbb{Z}$ and once for $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$) if I could.

Comment: Surely you know it, but for completeness (pun coming), one can alternatively order the groups $\mathbb Z/n$ "the other way around" and look at their inverse limit. But that is also not $\mathbb Z$, rather $\widehat{\mathbb Z}$, the profinite completion of the integers (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profinite_integer, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/256732/96384), whose additive group also has tons of automorphisms. (And which is intimately related to $\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$.)

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg: Of course. That is, after all, how you get the $p$-adic integers in the first place! But it seemed clear that the OP was looking at cyclic groups as getting “larger and larger”, rather than projecting down on each other...

Answer (score 6):

If $f$ is an automorphism of $\Bbb Z$, then there is some $m\in\Bbb Z$ such that $f(m)=1$, and therefore $mf(1)=1$. But this is possibly only if $m=\pm1$. So, either you have $f(1)=1$ or $f(-1)=1(\iff f(1)=-1)$.

But if you are working with $\Bbb Z_n$, then there is no this restriction that $mf(1)=1\iff m=\pm1$.

Answer (score 3):

All these groups are 1-generated.  Thus, the image of a generator must be a generator. (Isomorphisms preserve such things.) But
$\Bbb Z$ has only two generators, whereas $\Bbb Z_n$ can have many.  In fact, the number of automorphisms of $\Bbb Z_n$ equals the number of its generators.