# The direct limit of roots of unity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, limits-colimits

Let $\mu_n$ denote the group of $n$-th roots of unity. In $\mathbb{C}$, this group has exactly $n$ elements. For a positive integer $n$ and a prime number $p$, using the canonical isomorphisms $\mu_{p^n} \cong \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$ as a direct system of factor groups, and the multiplication-by-$p$ homomorphisms $$\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/p^{n+1}\mathbb{Z},$$
one sees that the direct limit of this system is the *Prüfer group*
$$\mathbb{Z}(p^\infty) = \{x \in \mathbb{C}^\times: x^{p^n} = 1\,\, \mathrm{for\,\,some} \,\,n\}.$$

Similarly, as seen in this question [Union of all finite cyclic groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1016124/union-of-all-finite-cyclic-groups), we can consider a direct system of cyclic group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and homomorphisms $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ if $n|m$. The resulting direct limit is seen to be $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$, the set of rational numbers under addition modulo $1$. We have
$$\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} = \bigoplus_p \mathbb{Z}(p^\infty).$$

**Question.** Can we view $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ as being isomorphic to $\mu_\infty = \{x \in \mathbb{C}^\times:x^n = 1\,\,\mathrm{for\,\,some}\,\, n\in \mathbb{Z}^+\}$, i.e., the subgroup of all roots of unity? If so, is there any way to define the isomorphism?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, send $a/b \in \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ to $\zeta_{b}^{a}$, where $\zeta_{b}$ is a primitive $b$-th root of unity.

Comment: Indeed... should've given some more thought before posting... Thanks!

Comment: This is $\frac ab\mapsto e^{2\pi i\frac ab}$.

Comment: This is ill- or under-defined. You need to make an infinite number of arbitrary choices - a different primitive root $\zeta_b$ for each $b$ - and you need to synchronize the choices appropriately (so for example the primitive $9$th root cubed equals the primitive $3$rd root, etc.) Way simpler to just say $x\mapsto\exp(2\pi i x)$.